# Angular 2 extract data from a response

Tags: angular

I am trying to extract data from a response with no luck. Can you tell me where is the issue.

```
this.tite = data.result[0].LinkID;
this.tite = data.result[1].LinkName;
```

component.html

```
<div class="team">
    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
<div>
```

object

```
getLinks{"result":{"LinkID":1,"LinkName":"Financial Planning Reports Admin"}}
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { NavMenuService } from './navmenu/navMenu.service';
//import { ITitle } from './app';

@Component({
    selector: 'pm-app',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    providers: [NavMenuService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    pageTitle: any[];
    tite: string;
    titileID: number;
    errorMessage: string;
    constructor(private _navMenuService: NavMenuService) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._navMenuService.getLinkName(600860)
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.tite = data.result[0].LinkID;
                this.tite = data.result[1].LinkName;

            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

    }

}
```

service.ts

```
getLinkName(LinkID: number) {

        return this._http.get(this._fileUploadAPI + 'GetLinks/'+ LinkID.toString())
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('getLinks' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }
```

Comment: I meant to write this.titleID=data.result[0].LinkID; this.tite = data.result[1].LinkName;

Comment: error:core.umd.js:2838 EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'LinkID' of undefined. core.umd.js:2838 EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'LinkName' of undefined

Comment: if i change it to  ngOnInit(): void {
        this._navMenuService.getLinkName(600860)
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.title = data.result[0];
                this.titleID = data.result[1];
                
            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    
    }I get no error but the title is not showing

Comment: also in my component.ts : I have tite: string;
    titileID: number;

Comment: you might try safe nav operator, it doesn't work right now.

Comment: what, I am not following :)

Comment: Please add all of your comments in as edit to your question.  What you've just done is make your post really hard to read/understand.  Which means people are going to be more likely to just skip over it.  Please see [Ask].  You also didn't even bother to take the 2-minute site [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result property of your data returned from the service is not an array based on your console output above (rather it is just an object). Remove the indices and it should work.

```
this.titleID = data.result.LinkID;
this.title = data.result.LinkName;
```